# Error (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When the AJAX is called I always get these errors:
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE or net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I also tryed different browsers (Chrome and Edge) but it is only working on localhost.

Thanks for all your help and support.

My PHP code (register.php):

```
    require_once 'mysql_conn.php';
    // username and password sent from form 
    $myUsername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
    $myPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
    $myRepPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['rep_password']); 

    if($myPassword == $myRepPassword && strlen($myUsername) >= 3 && strlen($myPassword) >= 8)
    {
        $userCheck = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$myUsername'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$userCheck);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


        if($count > 0)
        {
           echo "This user already exists";
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$myUsername', '$myPassword')";

            if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
            }
            $db->close();
        }            
    }  
    else
    {
        echo "Please check the values you inserted";
    }
```

and the AJAX call:

```
        $(function () {
            $('form').submit(function (e) {                      

                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'register.php',                
                    data: {username:username, password:password, rep_password:rep_password},
                    success: function (data) {
                        errorHandling(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: You need to debug your PHP first. Turn on error reporting and display and hit the php directly. Also check your php logs for error conditions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but I solved it by deleting and re-creating the register.php file